# How to add a function definition to the glossary

Tags: symbols, glossary

I'm using the glossaries package for the first time in a thesis document.  Everything works for simple symbols, e.g.

```
\newglossaryentry{Ndist}{name=$\mathcal{N}$, description={normal distribution}}
```

[image]

But when I try to define the normal distribution like this

```
\newglossaryentry{Ndist}{name=$\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, description={normal distribution of mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$}}
```

I get errors, including:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. ...ion of mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$}}
Package xkeyval Error: `\sigma ^2)$' undefined in families `glossentry'. ...ion of mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$}}
Missing $ inserted. ...tentrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{20}}}
Missing $ inserted. ...from the normal distribution, \gls{Ndist},
Overriding \printglossary
Overriding `theglossary' environment

...
```

I also get this warning in both cases, but not sure if it is significant:

```
name{glo:Ndist} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

Comment: Further investigation suggests that you can't use a comma in a symbol name.  Is that the problem and are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, the issue is the comma in the name because `glossaries` takes it for the separator between fields of the definition. Simply surrounding the value of `name` in curly braces does the trick for me:

```latex
\newglossaryentry{Ndist}{
  name={$\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$},
  description={normal distribution of mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple solution!